# How optimize gulp-jade task

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gulp

I have task for compile jade to html

```
gulp.task('jade', function() {
var j = jade({});
j.on('error', function(e){
  gutil.log(e);
  j.end();
});
return gulp.src([
  'src/templates/**/*.jade',
  '!src/templates/mixins/**/*.jade',
  '!src/templates/index.jade'
])
.pipe(j)
.pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir+'/templates'))
.pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Compiling has 3 seconds after every change+save. How I can improve this process?

P.S. I use gulp-jade plugin.

Comment: SSD, more powerful hardware?

Comment: @vitr, not a solution =/ I have macbook pro with ssd and power <3

Comment: Are you sure it's the compiling that takes time? Use `console.time` to roughly measure the bottleneck

Comment: yeah, console.time, also try to get rid of connect.reload, let's see how faster it would be with pure compiling task.

Comment: @laggingreflex - yeap, I'm sure. Delete connect.reload(), from task. Nothing happens :/

Comment: @Max P what you mean nothing happens? you still have the generated files in output dir, maybe you have thousands of files

Comment: @vitr - I mean, 'nothing changed'. Task finished after 3 seconds. I have 30  jade pages.

Comment: @Max P, oh man, you can give me the files I'll run the task for a benchmark, if you want

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)

> File watcher that uses super-fast chokidar and emits vinyl objects.

gulp-watch will monitor a glob for changes (returned through file system events from [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar))

A project I work on watches around 20k files, which get compiled pretty much instantly.

**Option 2**

You can skip all config and run harp + browsersync easily. If your project doesn't do much more than compile from `src` to `dest` 1-on-1, you can set it up under a minute or so. There is [a gist of this](https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/a424cc1672461526e49f) to get started in no time *(disclaimer: I am the author of the gist)*.